# is there any sample program using Kentor.AuthServices.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kentor-authservices

I am using mvc4 and I need SAML2.0 for the security. I tried some samples with Component Pro but we need to purchase it and it has good documentation also.

I came to know about Kentor.AuthServices.MVC which is an open source and may i know whether there is any learning site where I can implement with mvc4.

Comment: Hi Anish, did you find any proper documentation on this ? I started to look at Kentor.AuthServices;

Comment: @anish FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen SAML software. TY

Answer (score 3):

There is a working SampleMvcApplication included in the [source on github](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices).